# What is an 'input segment' in the context of PGF decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations

Regarding PGF decorations, consider the two dimensions with the catchy names (p. 1001 of the TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a)

- `\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance` ... The remaining distance on the current input segment of the input path.
- `\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance` ... The completed distance on the current input segment of the input path.

I don't understand

1. **what an input *segment* is?**
2. **how PGF calculates the *remaining* (resp. *completed*) distance on the current input segment?**

---

The answer to the first question is complicated by the fact that there are several similar concepts that can be described as *input segments*.

1. An input segment is a part of the input path. Every path breaks down to zero or more parts. Generally speaking, a part starts with a `moveto` operation, and ends just before the next `moveto` operation or just before the next `pgfuse` operation, whichever comes first.
2. An input segment is the subset of the path that corresponds to a single path extending operation:

   > The input path may consist of many line and curve input segments (for example, a circle or an ellipse consists of four curves.)
   >   (bottom of p. 996)
3. The input path is broken into segments by the decoration automaton as follows: when the automaton enters a new state, `s`, the next segment is that subset of the input path from the end, `e`, of the previous segment to the point, `p`, further along the input path, whose curvilinear distance from `e` is specified by `s`'s `width` option.

Note that

- A segment(1) can consist of several segments(2).
- A segment(2) can consist of several segments(3).
- A segment(3) can span several segments(1) as well as several segments(2).

---

The answer to the second question is complicated by the following facts:

1. The decoration output path is not the same as the decoration input path.
2. 'The width the you provide need not be the “real”
   width of the segment, which allows decoration segments to overlap or to be spaced far apart.' (p. 997)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) arc (20:230:1 and 2);
```

this translates into `\pgfpathmoveto`, `\pgfpathlineto` etc. primitives. Each of these denote an input segment. If there are nested decorations these also become sub primitives and each of them are segments of the path that are input by the user.

The path length is calculated by the soft path layer which I don't know how to summarize. Once the total length is known the state machine starts updating the decorated path and at each step decreases the remaining distance registers based on the last decorated point.

Comment: How many input segments are there in the example path you gave?

Comment: @EvanAad two segments

Comment: Actually, there will be four input segments: 1 moveto, 1 lineto and _3_ curveto segments. Arcs are constructed using a series of rotated "sub-arcs" each of a maximum of 90 degrees and approximated using cubic Bézier curves.

Comment: @MarkWibrow If you want to go down that path :) But I think decoration state picks up the arc operation as one segment if you judge by the segmentlength register.

Comment: @percusse: OK, thanks. So this answers my 1st question. What you're saying is that my 2nd definition of an input segment is the correct one. Now, regarding my 2nd question, is the following statement true: the values of the dimension parameters I mentioned in the beginning of my original post are up-to-date at the beginning of every state's code, but then remain fixed until the end of the state's code, regardless of what may go on inside the code.

Comment: @EvanAad It all depends what you do with the decoration code. There is no *regardless* in TeX by nature.

Comment: @percusse: OK, fair enough. What I meant to say was: PGF will not update these variables for me while a state's code is being executed. Right? It will only update them for me in the twilight zone between states, when one state is transitioning to another state.

Comment: @EvanAad Why should it change it in the first place? At every question I'm repeating the same mantra of these tools. you have to experiment with them.